# Ticker(hover) in Ipad is not working once we click again

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using Bxlider jquery plugin. In the bxslider i configured

```
ticker:true,
tickerHover:true
```

In the laptop it is working fine. but it is not correctly working in ipad.
Ticker(hover) in Ipad is not working once we click again.

Comment: Are you sure it supports iPad? AFAIK, there is no hover event in mobile browsers, since there is no mouse.

Comment: if i touch images in ipad slide is stop and it is not start slide again.

Comment: sometimes pagination in bxslider is also wrong (ex: 5/3).